# What is this theorem about existence of a function maximum called?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

The following fairly obvious theorem is surprisingly commonly used:

Let $f: [0;+\infty)\mapsto [0;+\infty)$ be (right) differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)>0$,
$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} f(x) = 0$,
then $f$ reaches its maximum value in the *interior* of its domain,
i.e., $\exists m>0: x\ge0 \implies f(x)\le f(m)$.

**Does it have an *official* name?**

**PS**. Proof:

$f'(0)>0$ implies that there is a (small) $A>0$ such that $f(A)>0$ and
$x<A \implies f(x)\le f(A)$.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} f(x) = 0$ implies that there are
(big) $B>A$ and (small) $b$ such that $f(A)>b>0$ such that $x>B \implies f(x)<b$.

Since $[A;B]$ is compact, $f$ reaches its maximum on it at $m\in[A;B]$
(by the [Extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem)),
and the choice of $A$ and $B$ ensures that it is also a maximum on $[0;+\infty)$.

**PPS**. Without $f'(0)>0$ we cannot claim $m>0$ (only $m\ge0$).

Comment: $f'(0)>0$ but $f'(x)$ for $x>0$ does _not_ have to be positive.

Comment: Right. It was $f'(0)>0$, not $f'(x)>0$. Gotcha. Do you really need that assumption, though?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where the initial condition on the derivative comes into this; using the limit condition, doesn't this essentially reduce to the extreme value theorem?

Comment: @SeanClark: without it we have $m\ge 0$ not $m>0$.

Comment: But isn't it enough that $f$ be continuous?  I don't see where you use differentiability, except at $x=0.$

Comment: @saulspatz: yes, see PPPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this theorem is widely known under some specific name. Part of the reason might be that it is more or less an **immediate consequence of the [Extreme Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem)**, as is seen by the proof you give. If I'd use "your" theorem, I would probably refer to it as just that.